# jPanelMenu - Slide In from Right Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've just stared working with [jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/) for the first time. I have it working properly, except I'd like to customize it to slide in from the right edge, rather than the left.

I can see what's going on with Firebug and I understand the CSS I need to change in order to have it slide in from the right side. The problem is that jPanelMenu element is given an inline style to adjust it's position when the menu is visible.

I don't know how to edit that position without editing the javascript itself. Is this my only option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to edit the plugin itself. Version 1.1.0 added the option to override the slide direction.

This should work:

```
var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
  direction: 'right'
});
```

You can check out the documentation here: http://jpanelmenu.com/index.html#options-direction

Comment: Ahhh perfect! I must have missed this option when I was looking for it in the documentation. Thanks!